# TcpInboundGateway ReplyChannel error handling

Tags: spring-integration

I am using SI 3.0.2 in the following screnario:

Client send a TCP socket message to me.

1. receiving a message with TCPInboundGateway
2. transform the message and send forward to a REST service with HttpOutboundGateway
3. receiving the HTTP response and transform it again
4. sending back the transformed message to the client through TCPInboundGateway replyChannel

The Client receive my answer.

Unfortunately I depend on a bad quality network which is sometime disconnecting between the client and my SI server. The other direction (HTTP REST) is stable. So I would like to detect when the client disconnected while the SI server was communicating to the REST service.

I found a solution tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter and I can catch the TcpConnectionExceptionEvent but unfortunately it doesn't contain any information about the original message or the any header information what I put there.

How can I solve this problem ?

Any help would be welcome! Thank you !

My exact Exception is:

```
01 júl. 2014 16:51:35,504 ERROR pool-1-thread-2 org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway:118 - Failed to send reply
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.serialize(ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.serialize(ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.java:31)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.send(TcpNetConnection.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only way to do what you want would be to add an interceptor to the `TcpConnection` and catch the exception in the `send()` method.

[Documentation is here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors), but I just noticed a bug (in the docs); the interceptor must extend `TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport` and just override the `send()` method...

```
try {
    super.send(message);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Another alternative is to use collaborating channel adapters instead of an inbound gateway; that way, you can put an error channel on the inbound adapter which will get an `ErrorMessage`  when the send to the outbound adapter fails. The downstream flow must retain the `ip_connectionId` header for this to work.

Comment: Added another alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Gary. I chose the second option and it works great !